# Where is the infinite loop here that happens only on iPhone, but not in the editor?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Ok, Ive had this in past where infinite loops/freezes happen on device/iphone but not in editor - and no error message. No crash just freezes.

Ive run Debug.Logs and tried more delays but I dont know what is causing iPhone to freeze/some infinite loop here. FPS drops too, I checked.

Basically I tried to spawn a set number of objects on planes that grow and more get added to scene as this spawn process occurs. The spawn process stops once a max upper limit of objects has been exceeded.

Here's how I do this, works great in editor -

**PART 1:**

```
if(anchorManager.CloneNumberGet() > 0) //first was placed
        {
            hasTriedSpawn = true;
            //StartCoroutine (spawnAllTiers (30));
            TriggerTierSpawn(); //sets off whole thing
        }
```

**PART 2:**

```
    public void TriggerTierSpawn()
        {

            if (GameController.trackingReady) {

                World w = worlds[currentWorld];
                int max = w.numTiers + 10;

                if (tiersSpawned.Length < max && AreThereEmptyPlanes () && max <= GameController.spawnLimit) {

                    planesFilled.ToList ().Sort ((pair1, pair2) => pair1.Value.CompareTo (pair2.Value));
                    //orderedPlanes = planesFilled.Keys.ToList ();
                    print ("Running this loop");

                    foreach (KeyValuePair<GameObject, float> entry in planesFilled) {
                        GameObject plane = entry.Key;
                        //print ("P: "+plane);
                        if (CheckForEmptySpace (plane.GetComponentInChildren<BoxCollider> ().bounds) != absurdVector3 && plane.GetComponentInChildren<BoxCollider> ().bounds
                            != null && tiersSpawned.Length < max) {

                            StartCoroutine (spawnAllTiers (max, plane.GetComponentInChildren<BoxCollider> ().bounds));

                        }

                        //put a wait here

                    }
                } else if (tiersSpawned.Length < max) {
                    print ("Wait for more planes");
                } else {
                    //print ("REACHED MAX: "+max+" Num tiers: "+tiersSpawned.Length);
                }
            }
        }

public Vector3 CheckForEmptySpace (Bounds bounds)
    {
        float sphereRadius = tierDist;
            Vector3 startingPos = new Vector3 (UnityEngine.Random.Range(bounds.min.x, bounds.max.x), bounds.min.y, UnityEngine.Random.Range(bounds.min.z, bounds.max.z));
                // Loop, until empty adjacent space is found
                var spawnPos = startingPos; 
                while ( true )
                {
            if (!(Physics.CheckSphere(spawnPos, sphereRadius, 1 << 0)) )   // Check if area is empty
                        return spawnPos;    // Return location
                    else
                    {
                        // Not empty, so gradually move position down. If we hit the boundary edge, move and start again from the opposite edge.
                        var shiftAmount = 0.5f;
                        spawnPos.z -= shiftAmount;

                    if ( spawnPos.z < bounds.min.z )
                        {
                            spawnPos.z = bounds.max.z;
                            spawnPos.x += shiftAmount;

                    if ( spawnPos.x > bounds.max.x )
                        spawnPos.x = bounds.min.x;

                        }
                        // If we reach back to a close radius of the starting point, then we didn't find any empty spots
                        var proximity = (spawnPos - startingPos).sqrMagnitude;
                        var range = shiftAmount-0.1;    // Slight 0.1 buffer so it ignores our initial proximity to the start point
                        if ( proximity < range*range )  // Square the range
                        {
                            Debug.Log( "PLANE FULL - an empty location could not be found" ); //means plane is FULL
                    return absurdVector3;
                        }
                    }
                }
    }
```

**PART 3:**

```
public IEnumerator spawnAllTiers(int maxNum, Bounds bounds)
    {

                while (tiersSpawned.Length < maxNum) { //still has space
                    Tier t = getNextTier ();

                    //Vector3 newPos = new Vector3 (UnityEngine.Random.Range(GetGrid ().bounds.min.x, GetGrid ().bounds.max.x), GetGrid ().bounds.min.y, UnityEngine.Random.Range(GetGrid ().bounds.min.z, GetGrid ().bounds.max.z));

                    Vector3 newPos = CheckForEmptySpace (bounds);

                    if(bounds.Contains(newPos) && t) //meaning not 200 so it is there
                    {
                        spawnTier (newPos, t);
                    }

                    platformsSpawned = GameObject.FindObjectsOfType<Platform> ();
                    tiersSpawned = GameObject.FindObjectsOfType<Tier> ();

                    yield return new WaitForSeconds (0.3f); //increase this if have iphone problem

                    //START NEW --------------------
                    if (CheckForEmptySpace (bounds) ==  absurdVector3 && tiersSpawned.Length < maxNum)
                    {
                        break;
                    }
                }
        //maybe check for num times trying, or if size of all spawned tiers is greater than area approx
    }

Tier getNextTier()
    {
        Tier p = null;
        int j = UnityEngine.Random.Range (0, worlds [currentWorld].tiers.Count);

        p = worlds [currentWorld].tiers[j];
        return p;
}
//SPAWN NEXT TIER
    public void spawnTier(Vector3 position, Tier t) //if run out of plats THEN we spawn up like tree house
    {

    print ("SUCCESS - spawn "+position+"SPHERE: "+Physics.CheckSphere(position, tierDist, 1 << 0));
    Instantiate (t, position, Quaternion.identity);

    anchorManager.AddAnchor(t.gameObject);
}
```

I have no idea what to do here. Ideally I just need to fill up the planes, IF the max num objects hasnt been reached, as they come into existence.

EDIT- tried:

```
if(bounds.Contains(newPos) && t) //meaning not 200 so it is there
                        {
                            spawnTier (newPos, t);
                        } else {
                           break;
}
```

and just `spawnTier (newPos, t);`

Comment: Please take the time to format the code appropriately. The indentation is broken and makes the code hard to read

Comment: Is this a minimal example? There is an awful lot of code here. Which line(s) are critical to reproducing the issue?

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto Sorry, will keep in mind next time

Answer (score 2):

This looks dangerous

```
if(bounds.Contains(newPos) && t) //meaning not 200 so it is there
{
    spawnTier (newPos, t);
}
```

you are relying on this to get out of the while loop, but if the condition never happens, then you are stuck.  Given it takes some kind of bounds, potentially on platform you get a condition where this never happens. Or you are running out of tiers, and t is forever preventing getting into this section of code

I think you need an else clause if you don't spawn anything to make sure you get out of the loop.

Comment: Ok - I tried 2 things that would allow while loop to breakout (see edit) but no dice, freeze immediately

Comment: what happens if you comment the while part of your loop out ( as an experiment ). so just the `while (tiersSpawned.Length < maxNum)` part, leave the block there.   Just to see if it is the while loop that is freezing it

Comment: Wow - no actually. it isn't the while loop.

Comment: Maybe it's because TriggerTierSpawn() is being called continuously? Since the max isn't hit? Issue is I NEED to do this continuously I think, since the area where I can spawn/available spaces for objects is growing as new planes get added by user. Is there a better way to do that - maybe on a timer? Or check for only IF new planes have been instantiated?